# How do I allow the UPS World Ship application to bypass UAC?

Tags: windows-7, uac, windows-domain

I have found a way some time ago that allowed me to *whitelist* UAC from certain applications by using the **Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit**.  This had worked for quite some time, however, it no longer works.

The issue is the users are in a domain as standard users.  WorldShip only needs to update the shipping rates and it unfortunately it is rather often.  It does not update the software itself.  The `C:\UPS` folder has full admin rights to the shipping department.

I had contacted UPS but they seem not to care and offered no solution.  In fact, I have a gut feeling (despite how unlikely, but nevertheless) that they patched that method up when I complained to them last time about UAC issues.

Anyway, I used this method: http://www.ghacks.net/2010/07/08/get-rid-of-uac-prompts-with-microsofts-application-compatibility-toolkit/ in order to bypass UAC.  Since the actual updater only updates rates and not the program itself, there is no need to UAC elevation, so I just added the two exe files that are used for this endeavour.

Is there another method that can work?  Like removing the manifest that triggered it since it seems to me that UPS went out of their way to force UAC when it is not necessary at all since shippers just need the rates and the program only allows two ignores when prompted.

Comment: What version of WorldShip are you using specifically?

Comment: 2016 (19.0.24.0)

Comment: By using the, Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit, you are modifing and specifically creating the manifest for the executable.  The problem you actually have is that UPS is modifying the executable with those updates, which means, you would have to apply those manfest updates each time that happens.  The UAC requirements are because the program is accesing the LAN per the system requirements.

Comment: I am assuming then MSAC won't work? Prior to 2016 it worked fine. Are there any groups where I can increase group privileges say full admin only for that particular program?  FedEx has no such issues.

Comment: MSAC is working.  The problem is UPS is updating and replacing the exectuable, after you make changes to it, thus eliminating your manfest changes.

Comment: Okay so that means I need to delete the database and recreate it? It is possible this occurred post 2016 install.

Comment: You can modify the executable each time it is modified.  It working in the past doesn't really tell us anything, that was an older version, not the current version.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding it to the UAC white list by going through the task scheduler.
Source: http://lifehacker.com/how-to-eliminate-uac-prompts-for-specific-applications-493128966

> 1. In Task Scheduler, right-click "Task Scheduler Library" and select "New Folder" Name it whatever you would like.
> 2. Select the new folder and click "Create Task" (not "Create Basic Task")
> 3. Name the task something descriptive. Enable "Run with highest privileges," and select your OS under "Configure for."
> 4. Under the Actions tab, select "Start a program" in the Action dropdown if it isn't already. Click Browse and find your app's .exe
>      file (usually under Program Files on your C: drive).
> 5. (Laptops) Under Conditions tab, deselect "Start the task only if the computer is on AC power."
> 6. On your desktop, right click and select New > Shortcut.
> 7. Paste 'C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /RUN /TN "Name of folder\Name of task" into the text box.

just found another guide that has images which makes it a bit easier to follow (same method): http://www.techgainer.com/disable-uac-prompts-specific-programs-windows/

Comment: The problem with this method is that the enduser doesn't run the updater, ups software does.  There are two exe's that can be used for updating (something like updateRun.exe and runUpdate.exe) and those are the two files that have forced UAC.  Since the main ups software doesn't require UAC, I am not sure if that will help.

Comment: OK, well rename the actual exe files and create shortcuts with the original names, This way the program will use the shortcuts thereby not triggering UAC

Comment: Oh that makes sense, I will give that a go.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to UPS Worldship 2016, creating an Application Fix to "run as invoker" for C:\UPS\WSTD\runpatch.exe and registering the .sdb via sdbinstall.exe was all that was needed.

It appears that in UPS 2016, runpatch.exe is updated each time it is run, and there is an increment in the version number of the file.

If you take the defaults on the "matching information" window when creating your application fix - you are tying your .sdb to the version number of runpatch.exe at .sdb creation time. Since UPS is now populating and incrementing verison number at each update, your .sdb is no longer applicable.

Create a new .sdb and remove selection for any "matching information" that may change, in our example: Version fields...:

[image]